# Need to change the directory inside the shell script

Tags: linux, bash, linux-from-scratch

I need to change the directory inside the shellscript.i have tried below

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u rv bash
cd /opt/test
source /opt/rv/van.env
./rv.sh |grep "STATUS"
```

When I tried it didn't **cd** to that path and not executed th rv.sh.guide me with some ideas.

Fyi rv.sh path /opt/test/

Comment: Add `set -x` as the 2nd line in the script and rerun for debug output. and paste your code in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to solve 99% of the issues. Why not just run `/opt/test/rv.sh | grep "STATUS"` and avoid the directory change?

Comment: Sudo was a typo mistake.

Comment: Does user `rv` have execute permission in `/opt/test` for file `rv.sh`?

Comment: Yes it have execute permission.

Comment: What is the result of adding `set -x` as the 2nd line of the script?

Comment: It will have permission to execute the script.

Comment: I triggered the script but it's not changing the path inside the script to run the next step

Comment: Why not `sudo -u rv bash -c '/opt/test/rv.sh | grep "STATUS"'`

Comment: We can but before that I have to source the profile.pls Check the question I have added one more line.i.e line 3 sorry I forgot to add

Answer (score 2):

The following line:

```
sudo -u rv bash
```

Will launch a bash console as the user `rv` and then your entire script will halt until the program (i.e.: bash) ends.

Only after bash ends, the program will continue execution and run the last two lines.

The last two lines are running as part of the first script, therefor, they run as your user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're expecting `sudo` to execute the rest of the script in the users context but it is not interactive. It will invoke a separate bash instance and, once exited, resume the rest of the script afterwards.

You'll have to put together a separate script and run that with sudo. Running sudo inside of scripts is rarely a good idea. 
S.a. https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-inside-a-script

Comment: Or use `sudo -u rv bash -c ' rest in single quotes '`

Comment: @Juan Ramierz the two lines should need to run under rv user .and should need to execute output

Comment: @David if I give your command will it change the directory also?

Comment: If you really want to change the directory for the invoking user - which might not be what they expect -, then you'll have to do that before invoking `sudo`.

Comment: @milinger but I need some exact way to fire that script .

Comment: I have to sudo user rv otherwise the rv.sh will not work

Comment: I can fire sudo after cd .but the thing is it should change the directory path and execute the output